# Returning left of certain character and right of a certain character

Tags: mysql, sql

For every row in a column, I want to take the portion of the string to the left of a parenthesis and the portion of the string to the right of the parenthesis.

Number indexing will not work here because the next row might have the parenthesis at a different position

In other words I essentially want to eliminate the ( and ) and everything in between them.

FOR EXAMPLE
if the cell contains a string that says:

```
'I am using MySQL (version) 5.7'
```

I want it to read:

```
'I am using MySQL 5.7'
```

In advance, I appreciate the help. Thank You.

Nick

Comment: Andriy solution does the job in getting rid of the parenthesis. However because it is a concat it is using the portion of the string left after the parenthesis are taken out, and it is doubling that. How would I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function [Substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for this

**Update**

I think I understand what your problem is now, when there are no parentheses in the string then you get a duplicate output. Try this instead, I use a case to check if there is a right and left parantheses in the string  before doing a concat, otherwise I just select the field itself

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
     WHEN INSTR(name, '(') > 0 AND INSTR(name, ')') > 0 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '(', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ')', -1))         
  ELSE name
END AS label
FROM first
```

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: @Nick No, the answer posted by Andriy is what I meant (and it's working fine for me when I try it). If it's not working for you you need to show us what you tried and how it fails wont input and output examples.

Comment: @Nick added solution using regular expression

Comment: I appreciate the help Joakim but I'm not well acquainted with regex. Check out my last commnet on my post.

Comment: Also, could be wrong on this, but I don't think you can use regular expressions with version 5.7

Comment: I appreciate your help Joakim. It appears you found the right solution. I will upvote your answer when I have above a 15 rep.

Comment: Good job @JoakimDanielson !

Answer (score 0):

As Joakim already mentioned you can use substring_index:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('I am using MySQL (version) 5.7', '(', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX('I am using MySQL (version) 5.7', ')', -1));
```

you can try it in http://sqlfiddle.com/. SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`content`) VALUES
  ('I am using MySQL (version) 5.7'),
  ('The earth is (VERY - VERY) flat and rests on a bull\'s horn');
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(content, '(', 1),   
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(content, ')', -1))
       FROM docs;
```

OUTPUT:

- I am using MySQL 5.7
- The earth is flat and rests on a bull's horn

in MySQL 8.0+ you could also use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function

[image: SQL FIDDLE screenshot]

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index says:

> Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of the final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a case-sensitive match when searching for delim.

Comment: See my update in the answer, I tested it in SQL fiddle and it works properly

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was the answer but it isn't. It doesn't show the text after the closing parenthesis

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1, '(', 1), SUBSTRING(field1, ')', -1));
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote in my answer :).  `SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(content, '(', 1),   
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(content, ')', -1))
       FROM docs;`

Comment: Andriy, you used SUBSTRING_INDEX twice. That essentially duplicates the contents of the cells.

Comment: Correct, first time it searches for the first occurrence of the '(' from the beginning and returns text from the beginning till this index (ont inclusive), second time (with -1 argument), it searches for the first from the end occurrence of ')' and returns the text starting from this index (not inclusive) till the end. Please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: Andriy the concat is a problem. Yes, your solution does get rid of the parenthesis. But, it also doubles the string after the parenthesis are taken out. For instance if the cell says 123(4)5 it is reading as 12351235

Comment: You're not using substring_index in the second part of the concat which you must for this to work.